# JQuery plugin for image gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to find an image gallery plugin with an horizontal slider and opened with some kind of box.

Integration of two different different plugins, one with slider and lightbox didn't work out.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you google it: http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

Comment: Of course, I did. That's why I'm asking it here. Did you find a plugin I need in your link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look on this :

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/combine/portfolio/index.html#

Comment: I've some problems with this plugin. I can't find the sources. There's just a demo.

Comment: you have this link :http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/combine/portfolio/index.htm see the source html

Comment: I've tried it on my computer, but it doesn't work. After adding all necessary css and js files, but there're some additional links in css files too, so I thought maybe I can download this plugin with all files needed.